# Unable to set data to textField from tableView - on Mouseclick and Up and Down Arrow keys (H2 Database)

Tags: sql, database, javafx, h2

I am a recent user of the h2 database, I need some assistance with the SQL syntax.

I'm able to retrieve data from the h2 dB and set it into JavaFX tableView, On performing the mouseclick or buttonpress action (Up & Down arrows) the intended behaviour is to display the current row of data from the tableView into the textfields, below is the code.

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Invalid value "1" for parameter "parameterIndex" [90008-193]
```

I'm certain this exception is due to SQL grammar unique to the H2 database, as the placeholder `(' "+slnoField.getText()+" ' ")` works fine in other databases. Please could you suggest the correct syntax or a solution. Many thanks.

```java
  @FXML
  public void UpdateTable(){
      data.clear();
      try
      {
          conn = lrconn.getDatabaseConnection();
          String sql = "SELECT * from APP_TABLE ;
          pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
          rs = pst.executeQuery();
          while(rs.next())
          {

          data.add(new TestPOJO(
               rs.getString("SLNO"),
               rs.getString("NAME")
              ));
              Table.setItems(data);
          }
          pst.close();
          rs.close();
      }
      catch(Exception e1)
      {
          e1.printStackTrace();
      }

      Table.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent me) ->{
                  try{
                      conn = lrconn.getDatabaseConnection();
                      TestPOJO user = (TestPOJO)Table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
              String sql = "SELECT * from APP_TABLE where SLNO =' "+slnoField.getText()+" ' ";
                      pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                      pst.setString(1, user.getSLNO());
                      rs = pst.executeQuery();

                      while(rs.next()){
                      slnoField.setText(rs.getString("SLNO"));
                      nameField.setText(rs.getString("NAME"));
                      }
                      rs.close();
                      pst.close();
                  }catch(SQLException ex){
                      Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                  }

              }
      );

      Table.setOnKeyReleased((KeyEvent e) ->{
                  if(e.getCode() == KeyCode.UP || e.getCode() == KeyCode.DOWN){
                      try{
                          TestPOJO user = (TestPOJO)Table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
                          String sql = "SELECT * from APP_TABLE where SLNO =' "+slnoField.getText()+" ' ";
                          pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                          pst.setString(1, user.getSLNO());
                          rs = pst.executeQuery();
                          while(rs.next()){
                              slnoField.setText(rs.getString("SLNO"));
                              nameField.setText(rs.getString("NAME"));

                      catch(IOException | SQLException ex){
                          Logger.getLogger(FXMLDocumentController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                      }
                  }
              }
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not using the `PreparedStatement` correctly. Place `?` at locations where you want to insert parameters in the query string. You don't seem to add one of those:

```java
String sql = "SELECT * from APP_TABLE where SLNO = ?";
pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, user.getSLNO());
rs = pst.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Fabian, overlooked that!